# Maven- Getting dependencies from pom file

Tags: java, xml, maven, pom.xml

I need to get all the dependencies of a project, so to my knowledge, everything under

```
<dependencies> ... <dependencies> and <exclusions> ... </exclusions>
```

Is it possible to get all of these from the https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ by going to a specific project's pom file and parsing it or do I have to get the effective pom of that project and only then will I have all the dependencies?

EDIT 1: How can I generate the effective pom for lets say, 100 packages? Currently, I'm using this command :

```
mvn -DgroupId=junit -DartifactId=junit -Dversion=4.13.1 dependency:get # get the pom/jar
cd .m2/repository/junit/junit/4.13.1
cp junit-4.13.1.pom pom.xml
mvn help:effective-pom -Doutput=effective-pom.xml
```

How could I write something that does this for 100 different inputs lets say, so I dont have to manually do this 100 times

Comment: Every dependency can pull in other dependencies so yes, you will need the effective POM

Comment: Can you describe the purpose of your question? The dependencies are. downloaded  during the build ... ? You can use the maven-assembly-plugin to collect them into a directory or something different ...

Comment: Long story short, I am working on a project on analyzing packages of Maven, but first, I need to get the data, and I have all the packages already, I need to get their dependencies and create a graph based on this. I thought that I can just get the dependencies by parsing the pom found on https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/, but apparently, as @NicoVanBelle said, I need to get the effective pom of each package first and then get its dependencies.

Comment: The graph can printed out via `mvn dependency:tree`  https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html and also exported into different formats https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html#outputType

Answer (score 1):

You can list all the dependencies quite easily by taking advantage of the  [maven-dependency-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/list-mojo.html). You just have to open a shell and execute:

```
mvn -f my-project/pom.xml dependency:list
```

or

```
mvn -f my-project/pom.xml dependency:tree
```